# Using polar coordinates, how come we can plug in for r but sometimes we can't?

Tags: calculus

When we use polar coordinates in calculating integrals, how come sometimes we have

> $x = rcos\theta$
>
> $y = rsin\theta$
>
> $z = z$

However, sometimes we can write it like if $x^2+y^2 = 4$,

> $x = 2cos\theta$
> $y = 2sin\theta$

Comment: Because in that context, $r = 2$ because this is a circle of radius $2$... I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the first relation you mentioned is **always** true in polar coordinates. But, when you write:

$x^2+y^2=4$

We can make the substitutions $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, and we get:

$(r\cos(\theta))^2+(r\sin(\theta))^2=4$

$r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=4$

$r^2=4$

And because $r$, the radial line from the origin, is always positive,

$r=2$.

Now, plugging this back into our formulae for $x$ and $y$, we get that:

$x=2\cos(\theta)$ and $y=2\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

The value of $r$ tells you about the position of a point -- with polar coordinates in the plane, it tells you the distance from the point to the origin.  Using cylindrical coordinates in space, it tells you the distance from the point to the $z$-axis.

In some problems, there are different points with different $r$-coordinates, or maybe a moving point with a varying $r$-coordinate.  But if you are only considering points satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, then all of those points have $r$-coordinate $2$.  So while you still may use `r' in this context, it makes more sense just to write '2' to make things more concrete.